Show that convergence of mean square implies convergence of mean
Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let
$$\bar{y}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \qquad s_n =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2$$
Suppose there exists a real number $s$ for which $$s_n \to s$$
I would like to show there must then exists a real number $m$ for which
$$\bar{y}_n \to m$$
My idea was to show that $\{\bar{y}_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence using Jensen's inequality, but I haven't been able to work it out.

Try a counter-example with $y_i \in {-1,1}$.

This is not true in general.
For a counterexample, we construct the following sequence:
$$ (y_i)_i = \left( -1 , \underbrace{1}_{2^0 \ \text{ times }\ (-1)^0} , \underbrace{-1 , -1}_{2^1 \ \text{ times }\ (-1)^1} , \underbrace{1 ,  1 , 1 , 1}_{2^2 \ \text{ times }\ (-1)^2} , \ \underbrace{-1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1}_{2^3 \ \text{ times }\ (-1)^3}, 1,\ldots \right) $$
It is easy to see that for powers of two, say, for $n=2^k$ where $k\ge2$, we have that the mean $\bar{y}_{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{i=1}^{2^k} y_i$ is in the interval $[1/4,1/2]$ for odd $k$ and is in the interval $[-1/2 , -1/4]$ for even $k$. Having this oscillating behavior, it does not converge.
On the other hand, for the mean square, since $y_i^2 = 1$ for all $i$, we have $s_n =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 = 1$ for all $n$. It constantly equals $1$, so it converges to $s=1$.
As a result, convergence of mean square does not imply convergence of mean, in general.
